# Unity error: InvalidOperationException: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: unity-game-engine, webserver, assetbundle

so all of a sudden I'm getting this error in my unity project.

```
InvalidOperationException: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
    UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandler.GetCheckedDownloader[T] (UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UnityWebRequest/Public/DownloadHandler/DownloadHandler.bindings.cs:145)
    UnityEngine.Networking.DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent (UnityEngine.Networking.UnityWebRequest www) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UnityWebRequestAssetBundle/Public/DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.bindings.cs:64)
    API+<GetDisplayBundleRoutine>d__5.MoveNext () (at /Users/remy/Unity/AREA/Assets/Scripts/API.cs:58)
    UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/Coroutines.cs:17)
```

I'm using my own website/server to request an asset bundle. I believe I recently updated the php version to **7.4** of the webserver. Could that be part of the problem? No sure if that is related.

Underneath the script which I use to sort the asset bundles from the server within the app. Not sure if that is related to my current problem though.

```
I'm requesting bundle in my app via this php-script om the server. 
 // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit https://codexns.io/products/sftp_for_subime/settings for help
    
    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": false,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,
    
    "host": "ssh.strato.com",
    "user": "******",
    "password": "******",
    "port": "22",
    
    "remote_path": "/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",
    
    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],
    
    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

This is the script I use for api access:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class API : MonoBehaviour {

    const string BundleFolder = "https://www.remykonings.nl/AssetBundles/";
    const string ItemList = "https://www.remykonings.nl/ItemList.php";

    public void GetItemList(UnityAction<List<string>> callback) {
        StartCoroutine(GetItemListRoutine(callback));
    }

    IEnumerator GetItemListRoutine(UnityAction<List<string>> callback) {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(ItemList);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError) {
            Debug.Log("Network error");
        } else {
            string rawText = www.downloadHandler.text;
            //split string by comma
            string[] items = rawText.Split(',');
            //remove empty values and convert to list
            List<string> itemList = items.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
            //return list to caller
            callback.Invoke(itemList);
        }
    }

    public void GetBundleObject(string assetName, UnityAction<GameObject> callback, Transform bundleParent) {
        StartCoroutine(GetDisplayBundleRoutine(assetName, callback, bundleParent));
    }

    IEnumerator GetDisplayBundleRoutine(string assetName, UnityAction<GameObject> callback, Transform bundleParent) {

        string bundleURL = BundleFolder + assetName + "-";

        //append platform to asset bundle name
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        bundleURL += "Android";
#else
        bundleURL += "IOS";
#endif

        Debug.Log("Requesting bundle at " + bundleURL);

        //request asset bundle
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(bundleURL);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError) {
            Debug.Log("Network error");
        } else {
            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);
            if (bundle != null) {
                string rootAssetPath = bundle.GetAllAssetNames()[0];
                GameObject arObject = Instantiate(bundle.LoadAsset(rootAssetPath) as GameObject,bundleParent);
                bundle.Unload(false);
                callback(arObject);
            } else {
                Debug.Log("Not a valid asset bundle");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new at all of this. Hoping for some help :)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to perform this operation via something like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), just to see if everything is OK!!!! Are you sure no authentication-related header use to go with the request?

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming so there is a good change I'm not understanding all of it. If the request is of https, it requires a authentication-related header? (not sure what a header is in this regard tbh.) It could be that the server moved to https recently yes.

Comment: No no, `https` shouldn't be any issue, the error state `403-forbidden`, so it mostly relates to authorization. Some `Bearer-token` that needs to be send with the request, that you are missing might can be the case. Let me try it with postman and see I can get some idea.

Comment: I tried to make a request to `https://www.remykonings.nl/ItemList.php` and the response received is `keukenmat,`, but the name is suggesting that the response should contain a list, so seems like something is wrong in the `ItemList.php` file while sending response, as can be seen in this [request postman image output](https://imgur.com/a/iZ02Ub8)

Comment: [Response of AssetBundle link](https://imgur.com/a/JOJCp3C). Seems like the permission for the file are not properly set on the server for it to be downloaded or accessed from outside.

Comment: Thank you for checking it out via Postman. The list is correct as currently there is only one item on there.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) But I was hoping for some sort of a JSON object in its place, and the comma `,` at the end of the string seems dubious to me :-) Please do check the permissions of the AssetBundle file, that might can be the issue.

Comment: I'm wondering about the kind of permissions the files needs then. Besides the fact that the php version of the server has changed and it's https now, there is nothing that I have changed to is. Could you explain me perhaps how I can set these permissions on the server?

Comment: oh, im currently keeping the asset bundles in a google drive folder and I upload it from there. Could this be the problem? I've believe this could mean that certain permission might the affected?

Comment: Oke so, that was indeed the problem. Permissions of file can sometimes changes when they're saved in a virtual drive. I've upload the asset bundles from outside the Google Drive folder and requested the bundle from the app again. IT WORKED!

Thank you for helping me :) I appreciate your guidance and advice. That made me search in the right direction :)

Comment: Sorry couldn't see the messages as it was night time so went to sleep :-) But glad you made it through and sorted things out :-) For the rest, You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)